# How to parse through a .dat file and get patterns such as timestamps and file size of a .jar file declared inside

Tags: shell, ssh, regular-expression

I want to compare the size and timestamp of the following jar files in separate directories.

First data is fetched by:

```
grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+.*?test1.jar" Sample.dat
```

Output 1 is something like this:

```
29003 2015-04-24 15:56:16 XYZ_jar/java7/test1.jar
```

Second data is fetched by:

```
cd /dir1/foo/xyz/java7
stat test1.jar
```

Output 2 is something like this:

```
  File: `test1.jar'
  Size: 29003       Blocks: 64         IO Block: 1234   regular file
Device: ab12c/34567d    Inode: 1234567     Links: 1
Access: (0123/-rwxr-xr--)  Uid: (123456/foo)   Gid: ( 1234/  fooooo)
Access: 2015-06-01 04:00:03.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2015-04-24 15:56:16.000000000 -0500
Change: 2015-06-01 00:13:01.000000000 -0500
```

I need to compare the size and timestamp of Output 1 which is 29003 and  2015-04-24 15:56:16 respectively, to the size and Modify date of Output 2 , which is 29003 and Modify: 2015-04-24 15:56:16.000000000 -0500 respectively.

Current code/script based from answer:

```
cd /dir1/foo
output1=$( grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+.*?test1.jar" Sample.dat )

cd /dir1/foo/xyz/java7
size=$( stat -c "%s" $test1.jar )


refdate=$( awk '{print $4}' <<< "$output1" )
modt=$( stat -c "%y" yourfile2 | awk '{print $1}' )

print $refdate
print $size
print $modt


if [[ "$modt" == "$refdate" ]]
then echo equal date
else echo different date
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use format specifiers in `stat` to get the specific information:

```
stat -c "%s %Y" yourfile
```

To assign it individually for later comparison:

```
size=$( stat -c "%s" yourfile )
modt=$( stat -c "%Y" yourfile )
```

To compare an attribute of two files you may use, e.g.:

```
size1=$( stat -c "%s" yourfile1 )
size2=$( stat -c "%s" yourfile2 )

if [[ $size1 == $size2 ]]
then echo equal size
else echo different size
fi
```

This can also be done inline; using the arithmetic command it's:

```
if (( $( stat -c "%s" yourfile1 ) == $( stat -c "%s" yourfile2 ) ))
then echo equal size
else echo different size
fi
```

To compare against a string containing an ISO date in field 4 you need `stat -c "%y"`, e.g.:

```
refdate=$( awk '{print $4}' <<< "${output1}" )
modt=$( stat -c "%y" yourfile2 | awk '{print $1}' )

if [[ "$modt" == "$refdate" ]]
then echo equal date
else echo different date
fi
```

Comment: how do I compare them with output 1? I think I made the wrong approach with the perl command

Comment: @Philip Morris; I added the test to my answer.

Comment: but my first output is not a file. it is just a string for sample.dat . Also modt=$( stat -c "%Y" yourfile ) returned something like 1429908976 and not something like 2015-04-24 15:56:16

Comment: Can you help me reconstruct my 1st command for output 1 so it can be used as a variable?

Comment: @Philip Morris; I extended my answer. (Note the number you see with `%Y` are the seconds since Epoch; if you compare dates this form is usually more flexible. In your case you want to compare an ISO date format though, so you have to use `%y` instead (see my updated nswer).)

Comment: it is only printing equal date but when I print modt and refdate, it is not displaying anything =(

Comment: @Philip Morris; To assign to a string from the output of a command you need command substitution `$(...)`, as in: `output1=$( perl ... )`.

Comment: I changed the perl command to grep because of an error . output1=$( grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+.*?test1.jar" sample.dat )
print $output1 . It is still not functioning. size and modt is not printing anything

Comment: I added the current script to the question for your reference. I think the placeholders $4 is wrong because I changed perl to grep.

Comment: @Philip Morris; Yes, if with your changed code the requested data in output is now the 2nd field and not any more the 4th you have to adjust the respective field numbers for extraction.